# How to read const char* returned from C++ DLL in .NET Visual Basic application?

Tags: c++, .net, string, vba, dll

I have a C++ function in Win32 DLL with such signature:

`extern "C"  const char* __declspec( dllexport ) GetResultName( int index ) {`

Note the `const char*` string type.

How to read this Value in Visual Basic 2008 application?

Comment: Do you mean vba or vb.net?

Comment: Propably yes, I'm on C++-side so I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can import the function using the `DllImport` attribute and declare it as a `String`:

```
<DllImport("yourcppdll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Function GetResultName(index As Integer) As String
End Function
```